# Kerberos key Lifetime

Tags: authentication, kerberos, mit-kerberos, kdc, klist

I have a HTTP service running on my domain. But I have few doubts regarding how the life time for my HTTP service is decided. 
how long can a client be able to use my HTTP service ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Kerberos ticket has a *lifetime* (e.g. 10 hours) and a *renewable lifetime* (e.g. 7 days). As long as the ticket is still valid and is still renewable, you can request a "free" renewal -- no password required --, and the lifetime counter is reset (e.g. 10h to go, again).

When creating the ticket, each "lifetime" is set as the MIN() of 3 values:

- the max duration set in KDC server config (check the [MIT documentation](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/kdc_conf.html) under *max_life* and *max_renewable_life*)
- the standard duration in client config, typically in `/etc/krb5.conf` (check the [MIT documentation](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) under *ticket_lifetime* and *renew_lifetime*)
- the explicit duration requested by the client, if any (for instance the `kinit` command has `-l` and `-r` options)

Bottom line: if your KDC does not serve renewable tickets because `max_renewable_life = 0` then clients will have to get a new ticket every `max_life` (or less, if their local `ticket_lifetime` is smaller).

PS: if the ticket is stored in the default cache then you can use `klist` to check the end-of-(renewable)-life time.
PPS: I remember some complaints about Java API (JAAS) not allowing apps to request renewable Kerberos tickets... Check if it's still the case.