# Renewing a connection to Apache Phoenix (using Kerberos) fails after exactly 10 hours

Tags: java, apache, authentication, kerberos, apache-phoenix

I have a Java application with possibility to make some SQL select statements from Apache Phoenix. For this i'm using a principle with a keytab to create the connection. This is the class that support the connection :

```
public class PhoenixDriverConnect {
private static Connection conn;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhoenixDriverConnect.class);
private PhoenixDriverConnect(String DB_URL) {
    GetProperties getProperties = new GetProperties();
    try {
        Class.forName(getProperties.get("jdbc.driver"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        DriverManager.deregisterDriver(PhoenixDriver.INSTANCE);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, getProperties.getInfo());
        connTime = new DateTime().getMillis();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static synchronized Connection getConnection(String DB_URL) {

    // for the first connection conn == null
    if (conn == null ) {
        logger.info("create new connection....");
        new PhoenixDriverConnect(DB_URL);
        logger.info("create new connection done.");
    }

    return conn;
}
}
```

Here is driver code which creates the connection:

```
public synchronized Connection connect(final String url, final Properties info) throws SQLException {

    String principal = info == null ? null : (String)info.get("DelegationDriver.principal");
    String kt = info == null ? null : (String)info.get("DelegationDriver.keytab.file");
    String hadoopConfFile = info == null ? null : (String)info.get("hbase_site");
    String hbaseConfFile = info == null ? null : (String)info.get("core-site");

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

    if (hadoopConfFile != null) {
        logger.info("Adding conf1: " + hadoopConfFile);
        conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfFile));
    } else {
        logger.info("Hadoop core configuration is not provided");
    }
    if (hbaseConfFile != null) {
        logger.info("Adding conf2: " + hbaseConfFile);
        conf.addResource(new Path(hbaseConfFile));
    } else {
        logger.info("HBase configuration is not provided");
    }       

    conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    conf.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
    conf.set("hbase.security.authorization", "true");


    logger.info("DelegationDriver - connect - principal : " + principal);
    logger.info("DelegationDriver - connect - keytab file : " + kt);
    logger.info("DelegationDriver - connect - hadoop configuration file : " + hadoopConfFile);
    logger.info("DelegationDriver - connect - hbase configuration file : " + hbaseConfFile);   

    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);

    try {
      if (principal != null) {
          logger.info("Trying to login with the principal found in the properties (" + principal + ", keytab=" + kt + ")");
        if (kt == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("keytab is required, no property found");
        }
        if ((kt = kt.trim()).isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("keytab is required, found empty property");
        }
        this.ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, kt);

        //this.ugi.getLoginUser().reloginFromKeytab();
        logger.info("Logged by Kerberos with the principal/keytab found in the properties, ugi=" + (Object)this.ugi + ", ticket=" + (Object)this.ugi.getRealAuthenticationMethod());
      } else {
          logger.info("No principal found in the properties (DelegationDriver.principal and DelegationDriver.keytab.file), trying the current user if any");
        this.ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      logger.warning(e.getMessage());
      throw new RuntimeException("Can't login, principal found was " + principal + ", keytab=" + kt + '\n' + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    logger.info("Going to connect to Phoenix. UGI = " + (Object)this.ugi);
    Connection conn = (Connection)this.runWithSQLException(new PrivilegedSQLExceptionAction<Connection>(){

      @Override
      public Connection run() throws SQLException {
        return DelegationDriver.this.driver.connect(url, info);
      }
    });
    logger.info("Connection to phoenix done");
    return conn;
}
```

This works perfectly. Note: I start my application at 5pm, but after 10 hours at exactly at 3am I get this error:

```
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session expired
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.connectionEvent(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:606) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.process(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:517) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522) [zookeeper-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6-1569965]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498) [zookeeper-3.4.6.jar!/:3.4.6-1569965]
```

When I try to make a select I get this error:

```
2016-11-29 09:48:07.491 ERROR 6352 --- [ared--pool2-t18] o.a.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient   : SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179) ~[hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:609) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:154) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:735) ~[hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:732) ~[hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:732) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:885) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:854) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1180) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:32675) [hbase-protocol-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1615) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:92) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:89) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:95) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:56) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.getTable(MetaDataProtos.java:10665) [phoenix-core-4.4.0-HBase-1.1.jar!/:4.4.0-HBase-1.1]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1290) [phoenix-core-4.4.0-HBase-1.1.jar!/:4.4.0-HBase-1.1]
at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$7.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1277) [phoenix-core-4.4.0-HBase-1.1.jar!/:4.4.0-HBase-1.1]
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1741) [hbase-client-1.1.1.jar!/:1.1.1]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:343) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:145) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_112] ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot read from System.in
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:865) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:704) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:258) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getTicket(Krb5Util.java:158) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential$1.run(Krb5InitCredential.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getTgt(Krb5InitCredential.java:330) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
... 36 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, Java support of Kerberos is far from perfect: quoting [Hadoop and Kerberos, The Madness beyond the Gate](https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html) *"... the public APIs are too simplistic for the* [Hadoop] *authentication system ... brittle across versions and JDKs"*

One of these limitations is that Java cannot create *renewable* Kerberos tickets, and cannot renew an existing (e.g. created by `kinit`) renewable ticket. Therefore your `loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI()` creates a ticket that **will expire after 10 hours** (which is the typical setting for ticket lifetime).
For the record, the Hadoop auth library automatically spawns a background thread to try to renew its UGI ticket, but to no avail, because the ticket is not renewable.

Even if the ticket was renewable, it would eventually reach its end-of-renewable-life after 7 days (typical setting again), and **you would have to re-create it at some point**.

The standard solution is to spawn a background thread invoking `checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab()` periodically -- see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop) for a very elaborate explanation by a HortonWorks guru *(a colleague of the guy who wrote that GitBook about Hadoop & Kerberos)*

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452020/kerberos-key-lifetime) and [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy) for more context about Kerberos and UGI.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a try-catch around your execute statements to reinitialize the Kerberos principal and connection.