# Kerberos ticket expires on LINUX RHEL7

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, kerberos, windows-authentication

I am using Python to connect to a SQL server database using pypyodbc and Microsoft ODBC provide for SQl server driver.
It was looking for Kerberos ticket which I created by using following command:

```
$kinit sinXXXX4@CORP.XXXXX.NET
```

But it gets expired everyday, how can I make it not to expire?

```
[sinXXXX4@uXXXXXXXd102 HealthCheck]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_134202
Default principal: sinXXXX4@CORP.XXXXX.NET

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
03/09/2018 10:09:46  03/09/2018 20:09:46  
krbtgt/CORP.XXXXXX.NET@CORP.XXXXXX.NET
    renew until 03/10/2018 10:09:40
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Either request a longer lifetime with `kinit -l` or look at the `k5start` tool.

Comment: From a security standpoint, non-expiring (or even long-lived) tickets are a Bad Idea™. You can, however, renew an existing non-expired ticket using `kinit -R`. In your case, it looks like that buys you some extra time before having to re-authenticate.

Comment: Did you check this similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917698/hbase-with-kerberos-keep-a-htable-instance-open-more-than-10-hours?  Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453395/how-to-renew-expiring-kerberos-ticket-in-hbase?

Answer (score 0):

Lifetime of the kerberos ticket depends on the ticket lifetime value set in /etc/krb5.conf of KDC server.
The default value of this parameter is 24hours because of which your ticket is getting expired everyday.
You can change the value of **ticket_lifetime** in /etc/krb5.conf of KDC server and restart the kadmin service and krb5kdc service so that changes become effective.

Comment: `/sbin/service krb5kdc stop`, `/sbin/service kadmin stop`, `/sbin/service krb524 stop` to stop the service. `/sbin/service krb5kdc start`, `/sbin/service kadmin start`, `/sbin/service krb524 start` to start the service. Source: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-restart-kerberos-in-linux

Comment: @Nitin: these are the commands which will help in restarting the kdc related services once the changes are made in the /etc/krb5.conf present at KDC server for changing ticket lifetime.
Though I think restart of /sbin/service krb524 is not required. Only restarting service krb5kdc and kadmin will do the job.